# How do I make Ruby's object.inspect() return the real class name instead of #<Class>?

Tags: ruby

I've got a class:

```
class Product < SomeParent
end
```

When I do this:

```
p = Product.new()
puts p.inspect
```

I get the following output:

```
#<Class ...>
```

Instead of:

```
#<Product ...>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What `Product.ancestors` returns?

Comment: I'm having a hard time duplicating your problem, but it looks like it's related to the class inheritance: https://repl.it/GRrI

Comment: @mudasobwa It returns an array containing itself, its parents, and a bunch of Rails-related classes.  In addition to a few unnamed Modules.

Comment: The return value of `inspect` is intended for the eyes of humans, not to be an argument in code. In this case `Product.new.inspect
 => "#<Product:0x007fe35291f9a0>"`, which tells you what you want to know. I don't know how your return message could begin `#<Class`. Please restart IRB/PRY and try again.

Comment: `Class.new.inspect` returns `"#<Class:0x00000001727288>"`. Other than that, I don't see how you could get this result. Do you have any more code to share?

Comment: The standard questions apply: What version of Ruby are you using and on what platform? I see your code snippets above. Do they actually exhibit the issue or ar they simply an untested code summary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely going to be related to the class you're inheriting from, simply because I'm having a hard time duplicating your problem.

```
class SomeParent
end

class Product < SomeParent
end

p = Product.new()
puts p.inspect
```

=>

```
#<Product: ...>
```

Comment: Maybe the better question is: in what instances does inspect return Class instead of an actual name?

Comment: https://www.rubysteps.com/articles/2015/customize-your-ruby-classes-with-to-s-and-inspect/

Inspect can return whatever the class has defined it to return. We need to know more about the inherited class most likely.

Comment: one of its ancestors was returning bad data from to_s().  Thanks.

Comment: How could this be the best answer when it's not even an answer? Steve, it sounds like you don't have an actual question. If so, you should delete it.

Comment: The original question didn't have enough information to exactly solve the problem - so I suggested a likely trail.

Comment: So it should be a comment, not an answer.